# How to display tables data having foreign key c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two tables, `tableA` and `tableB`.

In `tableA` I have a column `id` as primary key and in `tableB`, `id` is a foreign key.

Now I want to show all these two table's data in a gridview by entering `id` no. As I created foreign key but it just show only one table data in gridview .

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [tableA]WHERE id=1", con);

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

and code for table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tableA] 
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL,
    [NAME] NCHAR(10) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

and tableB:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tableB] 
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL,
    [fathername] NCHAR(10) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [FK_tableB_ToTable] 
        FOREIGN KEY([Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[tableA]([Id])
 );
```

Please help I tried but can't.

Answer (score 1):

You can join tables like this

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select A.ID, A.Name, B.Id, B.fathername from [tableA] as A join [tableB] as B on A.id = B.Id WHERE A.id=1", con);
```

To save a little space i used aliases for tableA (A) and tableB (B).

This relation that you made is a bit pointless, because you can have father name in same table as name (`tableA`). If one father have two children, you'll have too many records...

To learn a bit more about joins, google a bit. [This](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) is one simple tutorial

Answer (score 0):

you should use inner join to show the results from both tables.
like this:

```
 cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.id where tableA.id=1", con);
      SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     dt = new DataTable();
     sda.Fill(dt);
         dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Is foreign key required for INNER JOIN of the table

Comment: @princekhan you can join two tables with columns of same type even if they don't have relation (FK). Inner join is just a type of join (along with left, right, outer and cross join)

Comment: But for example I have one tableone that contain 10 rows and tabletwo that contain 5 rows and I want to show these both table data together . will INNER JOIN fulfill the requirement

Comment: yes it will. as the name implies, inner join will show you rows from the two tables joint together which have a relation. (I mean the FK)